# Flattening categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Motivating example:
Given a ring, we can construct its lattice of ideals functorially
(with morphisms mapping to the preimage maps on ideals).
Next, we may flatten this category of lattices, obtaining a category
of pairs $(R,I)$ with morphisms $(R,I)\to(S,J)$ being morphisms $f:R\to S$
such that $I=f^*J$.
Finally, this category maps back to rings by sending $(R,I)\mapsto R/I$.

The idea of this construction is to clarify the preservation of some properties
of ideals by functoriality. Admittedly, this may be using a sledgehammer where
a mere hammer might suffice, but...
$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ob}{Ob}
\DeclareMathOperator{\S}{\mathcal{S}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ring}{\mathbf{Ring}}
$

The problem is the flattening step moving from a dependent sum of lattices $\sum_{r\in\Ring}I(R)$ to the set $\{(R,I)\mid I\in I(R)\}$.
It is unclear how to formulate it functorially.

Abstractly speaking, the question becomes:
Consider a subcategory $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathbf{Cat}$.
We can flatten $\S$ to $F(\S)$, losing its object structure,
by setting
$$\begin{align}
\Ob(F(\S))&=\biguplus_{S\in\Ob(\S)}\Ob(S)\\
\Hom_{F(\S)}(x,y)&=\Hom_S(x,y)\quad x,y\in S\in\Ob(\S)\\
\Hom_{F(\S)}(x,y)&=\{F\mid F\in\Hom_{\S}(S,T), F(x)=y\}\quad x\in S,y\in T; S,T\in\Ob(\S)
\end{align}$$
However, it is unclear how to formulate this as a functor from $\S$.

Side question: $n$-category theory seems to focus only on categories whose $\Hom$s are categories. This situation seems to suggest that it is interesting to consider categories whose *objects* are themselves categories, i.e. subcategories of $\mathbf{Cat}$.
At the very least, it is an elementary exercise that some algebraic structures may be considered as categories with certain properties/structure, motivating such inquiry.

Comment: Welcome to MO Gesh, I think your first question is an interesting one.  For your second one, the 2-Category {\bf Cat} has categories as objects (0-cells) and a Hom category between each two categories whose objects (1-cells) are functors and whose arrows (2-cells) are natural transformations, and this is a very well studied 2-category. The n-category of categories with categories as objects and functors as 1-cells and natural transformations as 2-cells and modifications as 3-cells and... seems to be the n-categorical version of what you’re looking for.

Comment: Right. In general, the idea would be to view (concrete) $1$-categories as subcategories of $\mathbf{Set}$, and then to start considering the subcategories of $\mathbf{Set},\mathbf{Cat},\mathbf{2-Cat},...$. Of course, one'd need to figure out how to add "categories with structure" to this picture (e.g. viewing rings as monoids internal to $\mathbf{Ab}$), but this basic picture seems worth studying at least.

Comment: Why restrict yourself to concrete categories? You can consider internal categories as a vast generalization of the ‘group as an object with certain arrows in a category with products’, ‘ring as a monoid internal to ${\bf Ab}$’, etc. since it is literally ‘a category as objects and arrows inside a category’ which yields the standard definition of a category when realized in ${\bf Set}$,  and all those algebraic structures are special cases of categories. You can consider internal categories inside higher categories too.

Comment: Ooh, nice. Didn't put the pieces together, thanks!

Comment: No problem, category theory is tasty food for thought :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction you’re describing can be seen as the **[Grothendieck construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction)**, turning the functor $\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}I : \mathrm{Rng}^\op \to \mathrm{Cat}$ into the total category $\int I$ (what you’ve called the *flattening*) with its projection functor $\pi_1 : \int I \to \mathrm{Rng}$.

Generally, the Grothendieck construction is (one direction of) a correspondence between pseudofunctors $\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\C^\op \to \newcommand{\Cat}{\mathrm{Cat}}\Cat$ and [Grothendieck fibrations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration) over $\C$ (that is, functors into $\C$ satisfying a certain lifting property), for any category $\C$.

Regarding your second question, on categories whose objects are themselves categories: I think most category theorists would be unlikely to phrase it that way, since a property defined literally in terms of what the objects *are* is categorically rather unnatural (not invariant under equivalence, for instance, or even isomorphism). But a categorically congenial version of the same idea is to consider (2-)categories equipped with a (2-)faithful (2-)functor to $\Cat$, thought of as being (2-)categories whose objects are categories equipped with some kind of extra structure (or just satisfying some extra property, if the functor is moreover faithful); I’ve heard these called *concrete 2-categories*, by analogy with [concrete categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category), categories whose objects may be seen as *sets* with extra structure.

Comment: Trying to understand the Grothendieck construction, but the nLab page suggests this is definitely on the right track. Thanks! As for the viewing categories of categories as categories equipped with faithful $\mathbf{Cat}$ valuations, this A) makes sense B) is less evil and C) neatly explains why nobody cares to put conditions on the object sets.